# Get FB user id of an invitable friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my js facebook app, I'm retrieving all the invitable friends of a user. This return an array of obects containing:

- Their name
- Their profile picture
- An invite token

However, I want them to be able to send a message to this invitable friend, therefore I need the user id of this user. Would their be a way to get this?

Cheers!

Comment: That is not possible

Answer (score 1):

You can get user ids of your friends by sending that invitable tokens to facebook Apprequest. In AppRequest's responce you will get a list of key "to" that contains the user ids of friends who has been invited by you. Thank You.

Comment: can you please elaborate more